# uncountable nouns and articles

Tags: uncountable-nouns

**This is a software.** Is this sentence incorrect? As per the explanation given, this has to be "This is software.", but I have seen the usage of "This is a software." even in newspapers. Could you please clarify this doubt for me.

Comment: As per what explanation given? You are correct, uncountable nouns (like plural nouns) do not take indefinite articles. Do you have an example of “a software” in a newspaper? It could be a typographical error, or it could be part of a larger phrase where software is an adjective and not a mass noun.

Answer (score 0):

Newspapers are not always the acme of perfection.  We have an online paper here in the U.S., Yahoo!, in which almost every article is filled with grammatical and spelling errors.  Ive heard that the UK Guardian used to be a home for errors.

You could say "this is a software program".  "Software" is a word like "sand".  You wouldn't say "this is a sand" - but you might say "this is a sand castle".